# How to check if a Month/Year is greater than current Month/Year in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if 08/2014 is greater than 02/2014..

How can I do that in Javascript?? Could someone help me please...

Currently I only check for future year. Here is the code snippet.

```
this.isDateGreaterThanCurrent=function(b){
    return parseInt(b)>parseInt(new Date().getFullYear());
};
```

Comment: I prefer [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), then .. `moment("08/2014", "MM/YYYY").isBefore(moment("02/2014", "MM/YYYY"))`. However, you're more than free to do this by hand. I would start by creating a function that took in "02/2014" and returns "2014-02"; then that can be compared *lexically* with a standard string compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date` objects can be *compared* with each other.  So instead of parsing them you can do it as `date` object itself.

```
function isDateGreaterThanToday(b) {
    var dS = b.split("/");
    var d1 = new Date(dS[1], (+dS[0] - 1));
    var today = new Date();
    if (d1 > today) {
        return "D is greater";
    } else {
        return "today is greater";
    }
}

console.log(isDateGreaterThanToday("08/2014"))
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/3fCbV/1/)

Answer (score 3):

With [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) (which I recommend), then ..

```
var d1 = moment("08/2014", "MM/YYYY")
var d2 = moment("02/2014", "MM/YYYY")
d1.isBefore(d2) // false
d1.isAfter(d2)  // true
```

However, this can be done by hand without much effort.

Create a function that took in "MM/YYYY" and returns "YYYY-MM". The result can then be compared with a standard string compare. The major-first component layout is one reason why a format like [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is nice - even as a string, it can be easily ordered.

```
function toPartialIso(str) {
    var m = str.match(/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/);
    if (m) {
        return m[2] + "-" + m[1]
    }
    throw "bad date!"
}

toPartialIso("08/2014") < toPartialIso("02/2014")  // false
toPartialIso("08/2014") > toPartialIso("02/2014")  // true
```

Answer (score 2):

construct two date object with

```
new Date(year, month)  //month start from 0 (ie january is 0)
```

as,

```
d1 = new Date(2014, 7)     // 08/2014   (month - 1)
d2 = new Date(2014, 1)     // 02/2014
```

Now check,

```
Date.parse(d1) > Date.parse(d2)
```

`Date.parse()`,  parses a string representation of a date and returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970, 00:00:00, local time.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there ...
Using the split method to create an array out of your date

```
this.isDateGreaterThanCurrent=function(b){

var a = b.split('/');

if(parseInt(a[1])>parseInt(new Date().getFullYear())) return true;
else if (parseInt(a[1]) == parseInt(new Date().getFullYear()) && parseInt(a[0])>parseInt(new Date().getMonth())+1)return true;

else return false;
};
```

dont forget getMonth returns values from 0 to 11, not from 1 to 12 !

Answer (score 1):

To compare two date which are in your format, we have to parse the dates and extract the month and year and compare them

Its preffered to use some third party library

1. [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)
2. [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

If you want to do this manually the sample code looks like

```
function checkMonths(month1, month2) {
        var m1 = month1.split("/");
        var m2 = month2.split("/");
        var res = -1;

        if( parseInt(m1[1] ) > parseInt(m2[1]) ) {
            res = 1;
        } else if(parseInt(m1[1] ) == parseInt(m2[1])) {
            if(parseInt(m1[0] ) > parseInt(m2[0])) {
                res = 1;
            } else if(parseInt(m1[0] ) == parseInt(m2[0])) {
                res = 0;
            } 
        }
        return res;
}
```

Working demo [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JGnYL/2/)